# Can split recursion be done by hand?

Tags: java, eclipse, recursion, split

I have this worksheet problem to work on, and I just don't see how it can be done by hand. Each method calls 2 more methods to run, so each one would call 2 more. I don't know how to keep track of any of it. I don't know how one would even find the answer besides putting it into Eclipse.

```
static int fun(int x) {
    if(x < 1) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return x + fun(x-1) + fun(x-2);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(fun(4));
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I got it right. Are you looking for a description like this: `fun(4) = 4 + fun(3) + fun(2) = 4 + [4 + fun(2) + fun(1)] + [4 + fun(1) + fun(0)] = ...`?

Comment: If what you want is the n-th term of the serie : Un = n + U(n-1) + U(n-2), may be you can check my answer

Answer (score 0):

First of all "split recursion" is not a term that I have come across before.  And Google thinks that I'm asking about how to implement a `split` function using recursion; e.g. splitting strings into words.

If you are asking if you can perform that calculation by hand (i.e. work out `fun(n)` for some value of `n`), then the answer is obviously Yes.  You just need a large enough piece of paper and some patience<sup>1</sup>.

If you are asking if it is possible to come up with a "closed form" equation for `fun(n)` ... I suspect that the answer is yes.  However that's a Maths question not a programming question.  (Basically, you map the declaration of  `fun` to a recurrence relation ... and solve it.  In this case, it probably requires 1st year Uni maths skills.  Once you have the closed form, it will be easy to prove correct by induction.)

If you are asking if there is a faster program to compute `fun(n)` then the answer is Yes:

- If you employ memoization, there is an `O(N)` solution.
- If you can derive the closed form, there is an `O(1)` solution.

(I'm assuming you can use `int` or `long` arithmetic.)

---

<sup>1 - Actually, for large enough values of N, you should be able to compute `fun(n)` faster with a pencil and paper (and intelligence) than running that program.  The program has complexity `(2^N)` ... as written.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Easier solution: Declare an array big enough to hold the values of `fun()` up to the one you require. When `fun(4)` is asked for, you need an `int[5]`. Fill in hard coded values for the first two elements, then in a loop fill in the remaining entries using the formula. Now your result is in the last element.

A possible space requirement optimization: All the time through the loop you only need the last two and the current value, so you need not store all the values in an array of size `x + 1`.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean functions that call itself more than once at times then Yes!

Base case: `x < 1 ==> 1`, thus `fun(-1)` as well as `fun(0)` substitutes to `1`

```
fun(1)              ; == [substitute default case with result]
1 + fun(0) + fun(-1); == [substitute base cases]
1 + 1 + 1           ; ==> 3

fun(2)              ; == [substitute default case with result]
2 + fun(1) + fun(0) ; == [substitute fun(1) with previously calculated result]
2 + 3 + fun(0)      ; == [substitute base cases]
2 + 3 + 1           ; ==> 6

fun(3)              ; == [substitute default case with result]
3 + fun(2) + fun(1) ; == [substitute with previously calculated result]
3 + 6 + 3           ; ==> 12

fun(4)              ; == [substitute default case with result]
4 + fun(3) + fun(2) ; == [substitute with previously calculated results]
4 + 12 + 6          ; ==> 22
```

You could have started with `fun(4)` like this:

```
fun(4) ; == [expand default cases]
4 + 
fun(3) + 
fun(2) ; == [expand default cases]
4 + 
3 + fun(2) + fun(1) +
2 + fun(1) + fun(0) ; == [expand fun(2) default case]

4 + 
3 + (2 + fun(1) + fun(0)) + fun(1) + 
2 + fun(1) + fun(0) ; == [group]

4 + 3 + 2*2 + 3*fun(1) + 2*fun(0) ; == [expand default cases]

4 + 3 + 2*2 + 2*fun(0) +
3*(1 + fun(0) + fun(-1)) ; == [group, group x<1 as b]

4 + 3+ 2*2 + 3*1 + 8*fun(b) ; == [expand base cases]
4 + 3+ 2*2 + 3*1 + 8*1      ; == [calculate]
; ==> 22
```

I find it slightly messier. Especially if you don't group the several calls together it can be a pain.

Notice that this cannot be done if the function result is not directly mapped to its argument. As a treat here is a better version of your function:

```
static int fun(int n) {
    return fun(n, 0, 1, 3);
}

static int fun(int n, int v, int a, int b) {
    return n >= v ? a : fun(n, v+1, b, a+b+n+2);
}
```

It seems to be consistent with the sequence [A066982](https://oeis.org/A066982) except it omits the first element.

Answer (score 0):

So what you want is the n-th term of the serie : Un = n + U(n-1) + U(n-2).

Since no one mentionned it, here's the tail-recursive version using 2 accumulators, of what you want to do in OCaml :

```
let f x =
  let rec f' acc' acc'' i =
    if i = x then i+acc''
    else f' (i+acc'') (i+acc'+acc'') (i+1)
  in f' 1 1 0
```

It's super fast if you're using a langage with tail-call optimization (like hum ... let say OCaml). Since you're not, here's the sad, inelegant, imperative version of it in Java:

```
public static int f (int x){
  int acc1 = 1 ,acc2 = 1;
  for (int i = 0; i<x; i++){
    int tmp = acc1;
    acc1 = i+acc2;
    acc2 = i+tmp+acc2;
  }
  return x+acc2;
}
```

As you can see, no need to use memoization or gigantic arrays or complicated things like that. A simple for loop can do the trick :).

You can get all the intermediary results by printing (x+acc2) inside de the body of the loop